# Why synchronized function does not prevent entry? (JAVA)

Tags: java

I have 2 classes that I would like to create a deadlock with them.
I tried to create two synchronized functions that read each other - and so the process will be stuck.
But instead of the process being stuck, the functions continue to call each other.
I did not understand why this happens, the synchronized keyword should stop a process from entering the function once there is another process in the same function.

---

**MyRun:**

```
public class MyRun extends Thread{
MyRun1 myRun1;

MyRun(){
    myRun1 = new MyRun1(this);
}

public synchronized boolean f(){
    System.out.println("MyRun.f()");
    while (!myRun1.f()){

    }

    return true;
}
}
```

**MyRun2:**

```
public class MyRun1 extends Thread {
MyRun myRun;

MyRun1(MyRun myRun){
    this.myRun = myRun;
}

public synchronized boolean f(){
    System.out.println("MyRun1.f()");
    while (!myRun.f()){}

    return true;
}
}
```

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    MyRun myRun = new MyRun();
    myRun.f();
}
```

**output:**

```
MyRun.f()
MyRun1.f()
MyRun.f()
MyRun1.f()
.
.
.
.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Comment: It seems that you are never starting your threads, all this code is running in the same thread.

Comment: myRun.f() in main func.

Comment: Having a class extending `Thread` is not enough, you have to call `start()` to effectively have a new thread.

Answer (score 3):

All of your code is running on the main thread, since you are not starting any additional threads. Therefore is doesn't matter whether your methods are `synchronized` or not, since the execution is sequential.

You have to call `myRun.start()` to start that `Thread`. And you have to override the `run()` method if you want the new thread to call `myRun.f()`.

You'll also have to start the other `Thread` (of type `MyRun1`) and override its `run` method.

P.S., instead of extending the `Thread` class, it is a better practice for your classes to implement the `Runnable` interface and you pass instances of them to the `Thread` constructor.

Comment: but why does the keyword synchronized not stop the entrance (for the second time) to the function f()?
even though it's a synchronous process?

Comment: @Aviad Because there's only one thread calling that method. `synchronized` would only lock other threads from entering the method concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Java synchronization is reentrant.

If a thread is executing a synchronized block, and the code inside that block directly or indirectly invokes code that tries to synchronize on the same object, it does not block.

Distilling it down:

```
synchronized (myRun) {
  synchronized (myRun1) {
    synchronized (myRun) {
      System.out.println("Hello");
    }
  }
}
```

Here, `Hello` will be printed, because the fact that `myRun` is already synchronized on doesn't block the inner block with synchronizes on it again.